# What parameters can i use to find similarity/dissimilarity between two unequal length binary strings?

Tags: algorithm, math, wolfram-mathematica, correlation, similarity

I need to find similarity/dissimilarity between two binary strings.They can be of unequal length.
First lets consider they are of equal length.
For example:

```
1001101010
1101000010
```

What kind of correlation coefficient/similarity and dissimilarity measurement we can use?What if lengths are unequal?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56972/144441

Comment: This is often used in image processing to find similar areas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: In Mathematica `EditDistance["1001101010", "1101000010"]` = 3. The strings can be of unequal length. See the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EditDistance.html) for details.